# Page Not Found Error PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have updated my website on server home page is working fine but innerpages are not working fine

```
 home page url-http://54.174.90.227/  - working
 innerpage url-http://54.174.90.227/advertise/  - not working
```

i checked my .htaccess file
RewriteEngine is on

```
     # enable apache modRewrite module #
     RewriteEngine on

     AddDefaultCharset utf-8

     #Protect - DOS
       LimitRequestBody 10000000

      # set files headers
     <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      <FilesMatch "\.(css|js|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|htc)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public, must-revalidate"
     </FilesMatch>
     </IfModule>

   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <filesMatch "(thumb_resize\.php|thumb_resize_fixed\.php|image_url\.php)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, must-revalidate"
    </filesMatch>
     </IfModule>

        #+SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      Options All -Indexes

  <Files .htaccess>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  </Files>

  # deflate static content
   <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/x-component 

  text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
```

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  ErrorDocument 403 "/public/error/404.php/"
   ErrorDocument 404 "/public/error/404.php/"
 ErrorDocument 406 "/public/error/404.php/"


# Pages User
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-\_\.]+)$ index.php?usr=$1 [QSA,L]

# Pages Search
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]

 # Pages Static
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

# Pages Status
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/(status)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?   usr=$1&action=$2&id_status=$3 

[QSA,L]

  # Pages User Action
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-\_\.]+)/(followers|following|favorites|media|info)$ index.php?usr=

$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]

#Thumb Resize Images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^thumb/([a-z0-9-_\.\/]+)$ thumb_resize.php?x=$1 [QSA,L]

 #Thumb Resize Images Fixed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^thumb_fixed/([a-z0-9-_\.\/]+)$ thumb_resize_fixed.php?x=$1 [QSA,L]

#sitemaps
RewriteRule ^public/sitemaps/sitemaps\.xml$ public/sitemaps/sitemaps.php [L]
```

please suggest me something.

Comment: Can we see your .htaccess file?

Comment: can you please take a look on configuration file  http://54.174.90.227/info.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to test it via decrementing or incrementing of items.

You will backup your `.htaccess` and delete everything from this. Then try, if base url is working and if url with advertise is working. I suppose, both url will be working. 
Then you will add the rules from backuped `.htaccess` one by one and observe, when it will break. Then you have the rule, which broke your pages.

Next let's look to the `httpd.conf` and to others similar apache config files. Check your `DocumentRoot` variable and also check, if you haven't set Alias to advertise directory.

Next check if `advertise` directory is in `/var/www/html` directory? So the files for advertise have to be in `/var/www/html/advertise` directory.

Is in `advertise` directory `index.php`?

Comment: I added to my answer steps for checking, if everything is properly configured. Let's try these points.